# insert to console "MrTerminal.exe" comand string from BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, console

Good day! get a trouble with ".bat" file:
I have an string "setDef=99" - i need to insert it to terminal "MrTerminal.exe"

something like this by using .bat file

```
@echo on
rem GOING TO WRITE TO TERMINAL1 
echo setDef=99 |& MrTerminal.exe
rem GOING TO WRITE TO TERMINAL2 
echo setDef=99 >& MrTerminal.exe
rem GOING TO WRITE TO TERMINAL3 
echo setDef=99 >>& MrTerminal.exe
```

nothing from this works correctly.
I am noob in CMD stuff, may be you know better way to do it?
Thanks guyz!

Comment: you want to pipe strings to `mrterminal.exe`? Is it already running process or it is a repl tool?

Comment: @npocmaka that process is already running when windows starts, i need to add to that exe a line with code and enter it by some method. i was thinking about .bat , but stuck on forwarding

Comment: Unless MrTerminal is actively looking for input from your script, what you're trying to do is not possible. You _might_ be able to use the SendKeys method of VBScript to emulate typing, but in my experience, it's pretty hit-or-miss.

Comment: Do you have any documentation on MrTerminal.exe from Mirae Corporation? Is this the correct application?